# Why am i getting a timeliness error from an API request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

below is my Python code to query data from an API. when I execute the code, I get the following error:

> "{'code': 40000, 'message': 'Timeliness error. Please check the
> request header X-Timestamp', 'data': None}"

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? this is the link to the API docs: https://docs.apis.iobscan.io/

```
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import time
​
base_url = 'https://apis.iobscan.io/'
​
params = {'chain': 'cosmoshub',
          'channel': 'channel-141',
          'port': 'transfer'
}
​
# Get the current timestamp, in seconds
timestamp = time.time()
​
# Format the timestamp as a string
timestamp_str = str(timestamp)
​
# Print the timestamp string
print(timestamp_str)
​
signing_string = f"X-Timestamp: {timestamp_str}\nURI: https://apis.iobscan.io/\nBody: requests.get('https://apis.iobscan.io/')"
​
secret = b"MYAPISECRET"
​
# Compute the HMAC-SHA256 digest of the signing string
digest = hmac.new(secret, signing_string.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()
​
# Encode the digest as a base64 string
signature = base64.b64encode(digest)
print(signature)
​
​
headers = {'X-Api-Key': 'MYAPIKEY',
          'X-Timestamp': timestamp_str,
          'X-Signature': signature.decode("utf-8")
}
​
r = requests.get(base_url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Where is this coming from? `X-Timestamp: 1670920114.5788107`. Shouldn't you be using the `timestamp_str` value there?

Comment: @djs i just tried using `timestamp_str` but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you attach the docs for this API?

Comment: API Documentation will be needed to help you with this.

Comment: @djs here you go: https://docs.apis.iobscan.io/

Comment: @AshutoshYadav i've added the docs above

Comment: are you able to get a success response using Postman? And from which endpoint do you want to get data?

Comment: @AshutoshYadav i havent yet tried using postman. the endpoints are either the staging one: https://apis.iobscan.io/ibc/txs/{tx_hash}
or the production one: https://apis.iobscan.io/ibc/txs/{tx_hash}

you can insert the following value into ```tx_hash```: 0E47A5673D347BF88584F9A9735302F841AE9E55B20E0CC77F981F66F521C508